# How to add custom param to the external URL of the suitelet. How to access external url of the suitelet with authentication for security purpose

Tags: netsuite

Script deployment of the suitelet gave Url and  external url. External url is available when 'Available without login' is checked. How to add a custom param to this external url so that URL can be accessed only when the custom param value is known.
Tried to update the deployment record but the externalurl field is not editable. Can we edit this url or generate new one in any other way.
I'm using netsuite api 2.0

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to edit the Internal/External URL on the deployment. You can add any custom parameters you'd like on the call (except: e, id, cp, l, popup, s, d, _nodrop, sc, sticky, print, email, q, si, st, r, displayonly, nodisplay, deploy, script)

You can access your parameter's value within your Suitelet script:

```
var myParam = context.request.parameters.<your custom parameter name>;
if (myParam === <predetermined value or hash>) {
    // continue code
} else {
    // return 400 response code
}
```